# cmd prompt works fine, but Batch file cannot handle % strings

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have this image sitting in my folder named

`hello%5B1%5D.png`

I run this command prompt script to copy an image with a new name

`COPY "hello%5B1%5D.png" "New_Image_Name.png"`

which works fine

but if I dump it inside a .bat file and double click .bat, it outputs this instead:

`COPY "helloB1D.png" "New_Image_Name.png"`

taking out the **5** and **%** inside the image name.

Is there an option to allow command prompt to handle % strings as input values, if they are enclosed by double quotation marks? ""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
COPY "hello%%5B1%%5D.png" "New_Image_Name.png"
```